# Why does logical AND between [ ] and True/False returns [ ]?

Tags: python

I just ran into this case that I had never noticed before.
A few different cases:

```py
>>> [] and True
[]
>>> True and []
[]
>>> [] and False
[]
>>> False and []
False
```

What's the implementation logic behind this? I would expect the AND operator to return a boolean

Comment: `[]` is falsy. `[] and True` is therefore falsy, returning the first falsy operand via short-circuiting. The rest follow by analogy.

Comment: interestingly, the output is silenced when entering something like `True and None`. I assume that's because it returns `None`, correct?

Comment: @rv.kvetch AFAIK that's a detail of the REPL, not Python per se

Comment: @rv.kvetch When using the REPL, only the outputs which are not None get automatically printed.

Comment: ahh, totally makes sense. I tried entering just None in the REPL, and got blank output, which also confirms it for me.

Comment: Why is it called short circuiting? Doesn't seem like an intuitive name for this behavior.

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum Because if you do something like a() or b(), b will not be evaluated if a is true; the rest of the statement is short circuited.  It is important behaviour in C, which arguably is a parent language of Python.